# Null Pointer exception when creating Frame object reference

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null

I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting a NPE for the following code:

```
package kiboltgame;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.net.URL;

public class StartingClass extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

private Robot robot;
private Image image, character;
private Graphics second;
private URL base;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StartingClass sc = new StartingClass();
        sc.init();
    }

@Override
public void init() {

    setSize(800, 480);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("Q-Bot Alpha");
    try {
        base = getDocumentBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    // Image Setups
    character = getImage(base, "data/character.png");

}

@Override
public void start() {
    robot = new Robot();

    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        robot.update();
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void update(Graphics g) {
    if (image == null) {
        image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        second = image.getGraphics();
    }

    second.setColor(getBackground());
    second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    second.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(second);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(character, robot.getCenterX() - 61, robot.getCenterY() - 63, this);

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        System.out.println("Move up");
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        System.out.println("Move down");
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        robot.moveLeft();
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        robot.moveRight();
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        System.out.println("Jump");
        robot.jump();
        break;

    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        System.out.println("Stop moving up");
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        System.out.println("Stop moving down");
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        robot.stop();
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        robot.stop();
        break;

    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        System.out.println("Stop jumping");
        break;

    }

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

The exception apparently occurs for the local variable "frame".

I'm new to Java, and I'm closely following the Android Game Tutorial on Kilobolt.com, but even after compiling the reference code available on the site I receive the same Exception. I'm also using Netbeans to write and run everything. Also, I tried just a single call to getParent() but got the same NPE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I've been stuck at this point for some time now.

Comment: You don't *have* an instance variable called `frame`. You have a *local* variable called `frame` in `init`. Is that the one you mean? Why are you getting the "grandfather" frame? Is it possible that really you just need a single call to `getParent()`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning so I got a bit mixed up. I tried a single call to getParent() but it resulted in the same thing